# Print and Input all in one line

Tags: python

How do I get this all in one line? Do you see a more efficient way to do this as well?

```
import random  

# set the initial values
jersey = random.randint(1, 99)

print ("Who wears jersey no", jersey); input ("?");
```

The Output is:

```
Who wears jersey no 11
?
```

Comment: Don't be obsessed with doing it in one line. Readibility is more important. What if you want `"You entered John Smith for jersey no 11"` as a response to the input given (which by the way, you are not storing anywhere). If you make this into a one liner, you lose that ability.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do something like,

```
input("Who wears jersey no {}?".format(random.randint(1, 99)))
```

But don't stress about making one-liners all the time. Readability is important and if that means using multiple lines, do that instead.

Comment: Thank you. What does {} do exactly?

Comment: It just string formatting notation. It will add the random number to that position in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that having it all on one line is preferable, but you could do:

```
import random

a = raw_input('Who wears jersey no {}? '.format(random.randint(1,99)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, one alternative different from the above:

```
input ("Who wears jersey no %s ?" % random.randint(1, 99));
```

Comment: Depends on what the input type we wanna get. %s for a string, %d for integer.